# Unexpected behaviour for Fortran, C++ API

Tags: c++, c, fortran

I've developed a Fortran API for my C++ code. From Fortran, I pass on a string to the C++ function I bind to but the received string in is quite unexpected.

My API is in the following module `(api.f)`:

```
    module API

          use, intrinsic          :: ISO_C_Binding, only: C_double, c_char
          use, intrinsic          :: ISO_C_Binding, only: C_int
          use, intrinsic          :: ISO_C_Binding, only: C_ptr, C_NULL_ptr


          implicit none

    !     - Type object which binds to class object                                                                                      

          type     dp_t
          private
          type(C_ptr)             :: object = C_NULL_ptr
          end type dp_t

    !------------------------                                                                                                                      
    ! C function declarations                                                                                                                      
    !------------------------                                                                                                                      

          interface

             function  newcase_c (path, lenpath) result(this)
         &        bind(C, name="newcase")
             import

             type(C_ptr)                                    :: this
             character(kind=c_char)                         :: path(*)
             integer(kind=c_int)                            :: lenpath
             end function newcase_c
          end interface
      public     :: newcase_c, walldistance_c, releasemem_c
      public     :: dp_t

      CONTAINS

! Fortran wrapper routines to interface with C_wrappers                                                                                        

      subroutine newcase(this, path)

      type(dp_t), intent(out)        :: this
      character(:, kind=c_char),
     &     allocatable                     :: path
      integer(kind=c_int)                  :: sizepath

      write(*,*) "Trim Path: ", path, ":"
      write(*,*) "Len      : ", len(path)
      sizepath = len(path)
      this% object = newcase_c(path, sizepath)

      end subroutine newcase

    end module API
```

I call `newcase` as shown below somewhere in `main.f`:

```
      character(256, kind=c_char)   :: cwd
      character(:, kind=c_char)
     & , allocatable                :: trimpath
      type(dp_t)              :: dc

      call GETCWD(cwd)
      trimpath = trim(cwd)

      call newcase(dynacase, trimpath)
```

In my `.hpp` file I declare my `C` function. Note DP is a `class`.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    DP * newcase(char *dir, int lenpath);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In my `.cpp` I define my function `newcase` as:

```
DP * newcase(char *dir, int lenpath){
    std::string path = "";
    for(int i=0; i<lenpath; i++){
        path += dir[i];
    }
    std::cout << "Received path :" << path << ":" << std::endl;
    fs::path runDir(path);
    return new DP(runDir);
}
```

The problem is that sometimes, the string received by `newcase`(.cpp) is as expected:

```
Trim Path: /Users/abcdef/test_cases:
 Len      :           24
Received string /Users/abcdef/test_cases:
```

And sometimes it is just totally unexpected:

```
Trim Path: /Users/abcdef/test_cases:
 Len      :           24
Received string /Users/abcdef/test_casesG.stl:
```

My hunch is that there the null termination of a string may have something to do with this and I'm not sure how to address the issue. How could I resolve this? More clearly, why does `*dir` (.cpp) differ from `path` (.f) in `newcase_c`?

A suggested duplicate was:

> [ISO_C_BINDING Calling C routine from Fortran (with doubles and arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678961/iso-c-binding-calling-c-routine-from-fortran-with-doubles-and-arrays)

While the solution proposed there resolves my issue (as I can extract the correct length of the string) it doesn't talk about why the character array my C++ library receives differs from that passed on by Fortran.

Comment: I would suggest that you add a debugging printout of `lenpath` inside the `newcase` function. Then you might find that `lenpath` is not 24 and then you can start investigating why it was not 24 at the point where the `newcase` function was called.

Comment: *"Note DP is a class."* - `o.O` I don't see any class definition here. Also, if `DP` is a class, then how can you `#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    DP * newcase(char *dir, int lenpath);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif`. How should the C-compiler link to a CPP-object? I maybe wrong, about this, but whenever I need to call CPP code from C, I write an interface function that is in a *.cpp file but is a plain and simple function that C can link to. I just wonder how you don't get a linker error. p.s. building on the other comment, check the length of`dir`. Does it match with`lenpath`?

Comment: @JoeyMallone this works because `extern "C"` is just telling the compiler not to mangle names. As long as I don't use the overloading feature of `C++` this should work! So no surprise there. The length of `dir` doesn't matter because we have `lenpath`.

@Elias Length of `path`(fortran) is as expected. No worries there

Comment: @IanH I'm working with deferred size arrays.

Comment: The issue is with the `lenpath` argument. Without VALUE it is passed by reference (i.e. `int *`). In terms of the other argument, the C interface is actually using an assumed size array (as it should). The use of deferred shape (allocatable) arrays in the Fortran procedure is suspicious, as the example code makes no use of their capabilities.

Comment: @IanH indeed the VALUE attribute fixed the issue! Thanks!

Comment: @IanH This is not a duplicate question! Though your suggestion helps with solving the problem posed, it doesn't answer why the `*dir` receives a different value!

Comment: If I add the VALUE attribute appropriately to a reduced example here, the C and Fortran variables always have the same value.  Are you seeing differently?  Or are you asking "with this error in my code, why does my code give erroneous results?

Comment: @newkid Of course it is a duplicate. And the reason is explained clearly. The functions takes `int lenpath` by value so you have to pass it by `VALUE`. There is nothing more, you just have to be willing to actually read and think about the answer (and the comments here).

Comment: @VladimirF, I have read and comprehended the suggestion in the post and the comments. I'd like to emphasise that it is a problem not just with `lenpath` and when you read the edit about why the suggested duplicate differs from the answer I seek. Also the challenge is in reproducing this. As @IanH rightly says, a reduced example didn't generate the same issue. The primary difference right now seem to be in how the project and a reduced example are likely compiled.

Comment: Then try to make the question shorter so that it is clear where is the problem now, it is hard to see there. Also explain what is expected and unexpected about the output examples you show.